# How can I copy text from dialog boxes and menus?

Tags: dialog, japanese

I am learning Japanese and installed the OS in Japanese to immerse myself in the language. Sometimes I want to copy messages from windows, menus and dialog boxes so that I can look them up on the dictionary, but I cant. I saw that there there [many options for doing this in Windows](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-copy-text-or-error-messages-from-any-dialog-boxes-in-windows/). Are there any similar options available for Ubuntu?

Comment: According to comments in http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50406/how-do-i-copy-the-text-content-of-a-dialog-box-on-os-x  (about MacOS), it seems to depend on how the programmer codes the content. I couldn't find any links relating to Linux :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Make a screenshot and use OCR

1. Install OCR software

   ```
   sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
   sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr-jpn
   ```
2. Install a GUI for `tesseract`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gimagereader
   ```
3. Make a screenshot of your desktop or of a part of your desktop
4. Start `gimagereader` and start the recognizion

   [image]
5. Copy the text into the right pane and translate

Comment: Great idea!  :D :D :D

Comment: Not sure if the resolution is sufficient, but creative thinking!

Comment: I thought of the screenshot part, but adding the OCR is genius!

Comment: That is a lot of work and for a kludge work-around that, at best will guess what the text was. This is a useful, high priority feature. The program passes text to the dialog box, the dialog box itself should be able to regurgitatae its contents on demand.  It should not have anything to do with how any software other than the dialog box was coded.  I would imagine that is the Bailiwick of the DE or maybe X (im not too familiar with Linux but I have developed extensively for windows (where the feature had existed for years, then was removed, and because of a user revolt - reinstated).