# Text from dialog box can't be selected and copied

Tags: text, dialog

Text from dialog box can't be selected and copied. in the question:
[How can I copy text from dialog boxes and menus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689184/how-can-i-copy-text-from-dialog-boxes-and-menus)
I find a suggestion to make a screenshot and read the result with an OCR.
The above question is related to Japanese text, but I have the problem with plain english text.
Can You suggest a less complicated way to extract text from dialog boxes? Or may be this problem comes from a bug?
Note:If I create a dialog box from terminal using zenity the text in the box can be selected and copied.

Comment: I am afraid it is very hard to use a generic procedure to intercept the content of a dialogue box, if possible at all. It depends on the application, the (programming)  language etc. There is not one general way to generate dialogue boxes.

Comment: My problem is not with a dialog box from an application but with dialog boxes generated by Ubuntu system, for example now I have on the screen a crash report with Title: update-manager crashed with liblibclient0 in_show_transaction ... and would be very useful if I can cut this text to use it for a search on Google...

Comment: found a bug ... https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+bug/1273752

Comment: This should be standard in every OS.