# How to copy error message text from Wine alert box?

Tags: wine, clipboard

When a program in Wine displays an alert box in the process of crashing, how do I copy the text in the alert box?

I am trying to use the program [0CC-FamiTracker](http://hertzdevil.info/programs/) version 0.3.14.5 on Xubuntu 16.04 LTS (amd64). I have installed Wine, which correctly runs FamiTracker 0.4.6. But when I try to run 0CC-FamiTracker, which is a fork of FamiTracker (with [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/HertzDevil/0CC-FamiTracker)), it crashes immediately after displaying the main window.

[image: Message box]
MessageBox window whose text begins "This application has encountered a problem..."

How do I turn the contents of this window into text that I can paste into bug reports, questions, or other support channels? The text in this window doesn't respond in any way to dragging with the mouse over the text. [This post by Igal Tabachnik](http://hmemcpy.com/2009/02/awesome-tip-copy-text-from-any-messagebox-to-clipboard/) recommends pressing Ctrl+C to copy the text, but when I press Ctrl+C, switch to Mousepad, and press Ctrl+V, the text previously on the Clipboard is instead pasted because of [Bug 16860](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16860), which is CLOSED WONTFIX.

I don't want to install Windows just to try to copy out an error message for four reasons:

- The computer is a laptop with 2 GB of RAM, the largest module it accepts, which I assume is insufficient to run Linux, X, Xfce, VirtualBox, and Windows without thrashing swap.
- I lack a spare transferable Windows license.
- I have read horror stories about privacy violations in the current version of Windows.
- The behavior leading to the error probably differs between Windows and Wine.

Is retyping or OCR, as [A.B.'s answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/690583/232993) recommends, the only way?

Comment: I'm sorry to say that WINE is pretty useless. Better to install Virtualbox with a Windows OS guest. You'll be happier.

Comment: @heynnema I have addressed your comment in an edit to my question.

Comment: You might look at https://www.winehq.org/search?q=FamiTracker to see if they have a cure for the crashes.

Comment: That's why I wanted to know how to copy out the error message, in case I have to file a bug report.

Comment: Send email to the dev shown at https://github.com/HertzDevil

Comment: That's why I wanted to know how to copy out the error message, so that I could paste it into such an email.

Comment: See his forum at http://hertzdevil.info/forum/index.php/board,2.0.html, it has a similar bug report there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60321/discussion-between-damian-yerrick-and-heynnema).

Comment: Try upgrading to Wine 2.0, 1.6 is rather outdated: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

Comment: @QwertyChouskie Please see my question "[Testing an application in new Wine without losing access to current Wine](https://askubuntu.com/q/925514/232993)".