# Testing an application in new Wine without losing access to current Wine

Tags: package-management, wine, dependencies

How do I test a new version of Wine for one application without losing access to the distribution-packaged version of Wine that works for all my other applications?

I am trying to use the program [0CC-FamiTracker](http://hertzdevil.info/programs/) version 0.3.14.5 on Xubuntu 16.04 LTS (amd64). I have installed Wine 1.6.2 from Ubuntu's repository, which correctly runs other Windows applications that I use regularly, such as FCEUX (debugging version) and vanilla FamiTracker 0.4.6. But when I open 0CC-FamiTracker, after the main window is fully drawn, it immediately displays a MessageBox whose text I have partially retyped below:

> This application has encountered a problem and needs to close.
>
> Unhandled exception E06D7363.
>
> [...]

(The "[...]" is pending a solution to my previous question "[How to copy error message text from Wine alert box?](https://askubuntu.com/q/924453/232993)".)

From my other research, I have determined that "Unhandled exception E06D7363" is a catch-all for exceptions thrown in a Microsoft Visual C++ program that the program did not catch. (`6D 73 63` is the ASCII code for "msc".)

In a comment to my previous question "[How to copy error message text from Wine alert box?](https://askubuntu.com/q/924453/232993)", another user suggested testing the program in a newer version of Wine as described in "[Ubuntu - WineHQ Wiki](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu)". But a notice at the top of "Ubuntu - WineHQ Wiki" states:

> If you have previously installed a Wine package from another repository, please remove it and any packages that depend on it (e.g., wine-mono, wine-gecko, winetricks) before attempting to install the WineHQ packages, as they may cause dependency conflicts.

But if I uninstall older Wine packaged by Canonical to make way for newer Wine packaged by WineHQ, I fear losing the ability to run the working applications on which I depend. Is there a way to use both Wine packaged by Canonical and Wine packaged by WineHQ in parallel? Or would I need to install a second copy of Xubuntu in a virtual machine, in a separate partition, or on an external drive in order to have access to both?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is make a backup of the Wine prefix (`cp -r ~/.wine ~/.winebak`), try the upgrade, and if the new version causes issues, uninstall the new packages, reinstall `wine1.6`, remove `~/.wine`, and rename `~/.winebak` to `~/.wine`.

Rarely does Wine have regressions, especially if using the stable version (2.0.x).

Comment: One known regression is the loss of binfmt, which Ubuntu packages add but WineHQ packages do not.

Comment: All that means is instead running say `example.exe` in the terminal, you run `wine example.exe`.